# /bin/sh: apt: command not found", "stderr_lines": ["/bin/sh: apt: command not found"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines in awx

Tags: ansible-awx

If Im trying to install any packages from awx console using ansible playbook ,which pull it from git.

But its giving the below error in local ubuntu machine.

/bin/sh: apt: command not found", "stderr_lines": ["/bin/sh: apt: command not found"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines

or sometimes.

changed": false, "cmd": "apt-get update", "msg": "[Errno 2] No such file or directory", "rc

its working with yum package but not with opt package ,what might be the reason , please help on this.

If Im trying to install any packages from awx console using ansible playbook ,which pulls it from github.

---

- hosts: all
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
  tasks:

  - name: ensure apache is at the latest version 
    apt: name={{ item }} update_cache=yes
    with_items:

    - apache2

/bin/sh: apt: command not found", "stderr_lines": ["/bin/sh: apt: command not found"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to:

```
---
- hosts: all 
  become: True 
  tasks:
    - name: ensure apache is at the latest version 
      yum: 
        name: "{{ item }}" 
      update_cache: yes 
      with_items:
        - apache2
```

Your distribution does not has APT installed, which is the package manager. You're most likely on CentOS, which uses YUM as the package manager.

You should not use apt, use [yum](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/yum_module.html) instead

--***EDIT***--

There could be a couple of issues going on. First we'll verify if you have targeted the correct machine. Can you run this Ansible playbook:

```
---
- hosts: all 
  become: True 
  tasks:
    - name: test
      shell: touch /tmp/file.txt

    - name: ip address of targeted nodes
      debug: var=hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ansible_default_ipv4']['address']
```

Now, connect to your AWS node and can you verify the file is at `/tmp/file.txt`.

On the node itself, what happens when you run the commands `yum` and `apt`.

Also, run `ip -a` on your Ubuntu node, and verify the IP addresses match.

If APT is really missing, then you should reïnstall your machine. [Because of this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/491374/terminal-sudo-apt-get-command-not-found/491408)

Comment: No im using ubuntu machine and awx is running on  local machine which on ubuntu 18.04 ,not in centos.

Comment: can you perform "cat /etc/*release" and paste the output on pastebin or something.

Comment: nandeesh@host:~$ cat /etc/*release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=18.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=bionic
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.2 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS"
VERSION_ID="18.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=bionic
UBUNTU_CODENAME=bionic